# Node.js "An error occured while applying security settings"

Tags: node.js, failed-installation

I just launched the installation of Node.js on my computer (Windows 10) and it returned an error. See attached screenshot. I restarted the installation with my antivirus disabled but the same message came up. What should I do?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: check [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3431#issuecomment-283794115)

Comment: I tried this solution and it did not work.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I solved it by creating a user group called "authenticated users".

Comment: I followed this tutorial https://www.pcastuces.com/pratique/astuces/1312.htm to create a user group but I don't have the "local user and group" section so I don't see how to do it...

Comment: Hi, I'm running Windows 10 for workstations in Spannish.

1. Right click on "this machine" (este equipo) and then "manage" (administrar).
2. Go to "local users and groups" (usuarios y grupos locales), right click and "new group" (nuevo grupo).
3. Add a new group named "Authenticated users" and add the group "usuarios autentificados" to it (or the equivalent in your language). If you are running the OS in English just add your user to it and retry the installation. 

It works for me, sorry for my english, I'm doing my best.

Comment: My workstation is in Dutch, creating a group called "Authenticated Users" was enough, I didn't need to translate it.

Comment: Hello ! Thank you for your answer but I don't have access to the "local users and groups" tab in the "Computer Management" tool.

Answer (score 1):

creating a user group called "authenticated users"
works for me also, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by installing Node.js manually.
Thanks to all for your help anyway.